# Add hidden prefix and suffix to HTML input

Tags: html, input, prefix, suffix

How can I add Prefix and Suffix for the input
for example i have this input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control btn btn-default" name="userinput" size="100"  autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter word here">
```

When user enter `Hello` I want to send it to database like this `"Hello"`

is it something I have to it from Database or from html ?

Comment: You need another field, or you need to mangle this before you submit it. Why can't you do this server-side?

Comment: @tadman how to do it server-side? i am using phpmyadmin

Comment: Are you using PHP? phpMyAdmin is just an interface to your database. It's not a hosting platform.

Comment: yes i am using HTML PHP Bootstrap @tadman

Comment: So you're using PHP on the back-end. Do the appending there.